# Storing value in ASP.NET button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have this code:

```
DataTable characterDataTable = character.getAllCharacters();
foreach(DataRow row in characterDataTable.Rows)
{
  Button button = new Button();
  button.Text = row["character"].ToString();
  button.ID = row["character"].ToString() + "_btn";
  button.Click = "character_btn_Click";
}
```

The `characterDataTable` returns 3 rows with a `character` and `id` column for instance `char1`, `char2` and `char3`. Now I'm trying to create buttons depending on how many rows are retrieved and then trying to set a value to the button so when a button is clicked it will retrieve the value.. I want the value to be set as the `ID` of the row..

This is what I have at the moment:

```
protected void character_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Get value of clicked button
}
```

Does anyone know how to store a value in an ASP.NET button and retrieve it when it has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a click handler to a `Button`, you should do this:

```
button.Click += character_btn_Click;
```

You can use [`CommandName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass a "value" to the event handler. So the code becomes:

```
DataTable characterDataTable = character.getAllCharacters();
foreach(DataRow row in characterDataTable.Rows)
{
  Button button = new Button();
  button.Text = row["character"].ToString();
  button.ID = row["character"].ToString() + "_btn";
  button.CommandName = row["id"].ToString();
  button.Click += character_btn_Click;
}
```

The click handler is then:

```
void character_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string value = btn.CommandName;
}
```